# how to replace two chars with one char in string.split vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I am working on splitting explode strings to arrays so I can choose the data that I want. However, look at this..

```
If ProgressBar1.Value = 20 Then
            Dim rep As String = rtb.Text
            Dim replace As String
            replace = rep.Replace(vbLf, "^")
            rtb.Text = replace
```

I want to replace all line feeds sent to me. it works fine. but sometimes the module gives me two line feeds the results to " ^^ "

```
If ProgressBar1.Value = 30 Then
            Dim rtbnew As String = rtb.Text
            incomingip = rtbnew.Split("^")
            ip = incomingip(6).Split("="c)
            txtIP.Text = ip(1)

            ip = incomingip(7).Split("="c)
            txtMask.Text = ip(1)

            ip = incomingip(9).Split("="c)
            txtHost.Text = ip(1)

            ip = incomingip(8).Split("="c)
            txtDfg.Text = ip(1)

            ip = incomingip(14).Split("="c)
            txtBackupIP.Text = ip(1)

            ip = incomingip(5).Split("="c)
            cboDhcp.Text = ip(1)
        End If
```

here is the next line of code, as you can see, I am getting data per line split, so, if the module sent me double vbLf, it gives " ^^ " which means, the index inside ^^ is being counted and therefore, my arrays are shuffled. 
so, how can I replace single vbLf to ^ 
and double vbLf to ^ ? 
let's say, something like this..

```
string = mystring.Replace(one vbLf & two vbLf, "^")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace` instead:

```
replace = Regex.Replace(rep , string.format("({0})+", vbLf), "^")
```

It will replace every part of the string which match the patter, which will be `string.format("({0})+", vbLf)` (e.g. it will be `(|)+` when your `vbLf` is `|`). That pattern matches every one or more occurrences of `|`.

Comment: You should read about Regular Expressions. I've updated my answer with a little explanation, but you definitely should read more on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

The Split method has an overload that will give you an option to remove empties (StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).  Here is a short example

```
    Dim teststring As String = "This^is^a^^test"
    Dim parts() As String = teststring.Split(New Char() {"^"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each s As String In parts
        Debug.WriteLine(s)
    Next
```

Note double ^^ in the test string.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
rbt.txt = rbt.txt.replace(vblf,"^") 
While rtb.Text.contains("^^")
    rtb.txt = rbt.txt.replace("^^","^")
end while
```